# Why doesn't the usercard expand up when there is no space to expand down?

Tags: bug, user-card

This is a really minor issue, but I thought I'd bring it up anyway. When a tag is expanded (when you hover your mouse over it), it normally expands down, but will expand up if there isn't enough space on the screen. A user card only expands down, even if there isn't enough space. The card is then "clipped" by the edge of the browser's window.

Here is what an open tag looks like at the bottom of the browser window:

[image]

Here is what an open (and incomplete) user card looks like at the bottom of the window:

[image]

Can this be fixed? Is it worth fixing?

Comment: I've never come across this. Isn't the footer bigger than the maximum size for a usercard?

Comment: @minitech as in the browser window is too small rather than not enough space on the page.  I just tried it and it is the case but I'm not sure it's a widespread problem

Comment: @Rory Yeah, I wouldn't call it a "widespread" problem either. But it could be improved nonetheless.

Comment: I don't see a use. Just scroll down.